# Nvidia driver on Puppy Linux persistent USB

Tags: nvidia, hardware, puppy-linux

I'm having trouble trying to revive an old pre-built with Puppy Linux. The aforementioned pre-built is an Acer Aspire X3200 with the following specifications:

- Athlon II X2 4400+
- 1.5Gb DDR2
- No storage
- Nvidia GeForce 8200

See the idea is that this would be a media PC in the living room connected to the TV monitor via USB as I have no spare storage. Since it came with an Nvidia IGP of course all sorts of problem comes up:

- At first booting would just end in black screen, a quick Google search and I found a suggestion to load fossapup without kernel modules settings, which worked (but graphics would only show up using that option). However, the display resolution maxed out at 1280x1024, which means it doesn't show full screen on the TV (32" Sharp Aquos), which is not preferable.
- Turns out there is a legacy Nvidia 340.108 driver (that supports GeForce 8200) in the Puppy Package Manager (http://distro.ibiblio.org/puppylinux/pet_packages-fossa64/). Trying to install the aforementioned package I would be greeted with a "No Swap" warning (possibly due to running via USB), so I decided to ignore the error and install it anyway. Everything went well, booting with kernel modules settings would work fine as the cursor is displayed. However the screen would just flicker frantically and nothing can be seen but the cursor. Rebooting without kernel modules would produce the same result and technically the distro is unusable.

At this point I've given up for the day, though still curious:

- Is the use of USB the culprit and will using an SSD work? The motherboard probably only have SATA II interface but I suppose it's still better than a spinning disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out [it's an old and known issue about MSI interrupts that makes the driver fail to initialize](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/340.108/README/knownissues.html). Unfortunately to the best of my knowledge this issue never got properly fixed by Nvidia, but there's a workaround, which is simply just disabling MSI (major thanks to [these lovely](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/8200-igp-which-driver-version/32027/17) [people of the internet](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=272089)).

It was as simple as adding `options nvidia NVreg_EnableMSI=0` to a kernel module configuration file (it could be under any name; in my case, `/etc/modprobe.b/video.conf`), or adding `pci=nomsi` as one of the kernel boot command.

I also add the following to a config file (again, any name) to blacklist `nouveau`, as I read it can cause some problems:

```
blacklist nouveau

options nouveau modeset=0
```

Trying to add that was a hassle as the driver would just crash on login screen, so I added that through `GRUB > Ubuntu recovery mode > Drop to root`